# Manage shared state in Scala class

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I use actors when it comes to manage shared state while I am in Scala world.

Out of curiosity want to understand how others approach thread safety requirements in Scala **without** using Actors.

I understand answer may wary based on how small/big state requirements are but if you have simple state. e.g. following is a very simplified example

```
class MyEntityObj{
  private var keys = mutable.Set[Int]()

 def insertKey(key:Int) ={
   keys = keys + key
 }
 def persistKeys(keys:Set[Int) ={
   persistanceService.persist(keys)
 }
}
```

In some cases [Java concurrent collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) may come in handy but may not be appropriate every time. Again I know Actors is one way (and I already use Actors) but if not actors what other approaches you opt in for generally?

Comment: Other than designing a system that doesn't require explicit mutable state or using Java's concurrent collections to manage that state? How about Software Transactional Memory? Or something else? This question is so broad. Can you narrow it?

Comment: @Vikas, your question is *very* broad. Scala is just another programming language, even actors concept is not unique to it. You can use any approach you want, for example, java concurrent collection you've mentioned or futures or something else.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev futures .... for keeping a mutable state? sounds weird

Comment: @VladimirMatveev : I am confused too how can Futures be helpful in managing shared states? Not sure why question is very broad. I portrayed a sample with a mutable state in there and trying to see how other people will approach in implementing it?

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I'm sorry, I somehow thought about concurrency in general. Of course futures are not meant for that :)